# /settings/ads/ Keeps popping up while scraping Google

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I have a program that scrapes Google, it's an open source vulnerability scraper that uses `mechanize` to search Google. It uses a random search query provided in a text file to decide what to search for.

I'll post the main file and a link to the git due to the size of the program.

Anyways, I have this program that is used to scrape for sites, however, while it is scraping every now and then it comes across a 'URL' (I say that lightly) that looks like this:

```
[17:05:02 INFO]I'll run in default mode!
[17:05:02 INFO]I'm searching for possible SQL vulnerable sites, using search query inurl:/main.php?f1=

[17:05:04 SUCCESS]Site found: http://forix.autosport.com/main.php?l=0&c=1
[17:05:05 SUCCESS]Site found: https://zweeler.com/formula1/FantasyFormula12016/main.php?ref=103
[17:05:06 SUCCESS]Site found: https://en.zweeler.com/formula1/FantasyFormula1YearGame2015/main.php
[17:05:07 SUCCESS]Site found: http://modelcargo.com/main.php?mod=sambachoose&dep=samba
[17:05:08 SUCCESS]Site found: http://www.ukdirt.co.uk/main.php?P=rules&f=8
[17:05:09 SUCCESS]Site found: http://www.ukdirt.co.uk/main.php?P=tracks&g=2&d=2&m=0
[17:05:11 SUCCESS]Site found: http://zoohoo.sk/redir.php?q=v%FDsledok&url=http%3A%2F%2Flivescore.sk%2Fmain.php%3Flang%3Dsk
[17:05:12 SUCCESS]Site found: http://www.chemical-plus.com/main.php?f1=pearl_pigment.htm
[17:05:13 SUCCESS]Site found: http://www.fantasyf1.co/main.php
[17:05:14 SUCCESS]Site found: http://www.escritores.cl/base.php?f1=escritores/main.php
[17:05:15 SUCCESS]Site found: /settings/ads/preferences?hl=en #<= Right here
```

When this shows up, it completely crashes the program. I've tried doing the following:

```
next if urls == '/settings/ads/preferences?hl=en'
next if urls =~ /preferences?hl=en/
next if urls.split('/')[2] == 'ads/preferences?hl=en'
```

However, it keeps popping up. Also I should mention, the last 5 characters depend on your locations, so far I've seen:

```
hl=en
hl=ru
hl=ia
```

Does anybody have any idea what this is, I've done some research and literally can't find anything on it. Any help with this would be fantastic.

Main source:

```
#!/usr/local/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'rest-client'
require 'timeout'
require 'uri'
require 'fileutils'
require 'colored'
require 'yaml'
require 'date'
require 'optparse'
require 'tempfile'
require 'socket'
require 'net/http'
require_relative 'lib/modules/format.rb'
require_relative 'lib/modules/credits.rb'
require_relative 'lib/modules/legal.rb'
require_relative 'lib/modules/spider.rb'
require_relative 'lib/modules/copy.rb'
require_relative 'lib/modules/site_info.rb'

include Format
include Credits
include Legal
include Whitewidow
include Copy
include SiteInfo

PATH = Dir.pwd
VERSION = Whitewidow.version
SEARCH = File.readlines("#{PATH}/lib/search_query.txt").sample
info = YAML.load_file("#{PATH}/lib/rand-agents.yaml")
@user_agent = info['user_agents'][info.keys.sample]
OPTIONS = {}

def usage_page
  Format.usage("You can run me with the following flags: #{File.basename(__FILE__)} -[d|e|h] -[f] <path/to/file/if/any>")
  exit
end

def examples_page
  Format.usage('This is my examples page, I\'ll show you a few examples of how to get me to do what you want.')
  Format.usage('Running me with a file: whitewidow.rb -f <path/to/file> keep the file inside of one of my directories.')
  Format.usage('Running me default, if you don\'t want to use a file, because you don\'t think I can handle it, or for whatever reason, you can run me default by passing the Default flag: whitewidow.rb -d this will allow me to scrape Google for some SQL vuln sites, no guarentees though!')
  Format.usage('Running me with my Help flag will show you all options an explanation of what they do and how to use them')
  Format.usage('Running me without a flag will show you the usage page. Not descriptive at all but gets the point across')
end

OptionParser.new do |opt|
  opt.on('-f FILE', '--file FILE', 'Pass a file name to me, remember to drop the first slash. /tmp/txt.txt <= INCORRECT tmp/text.txt <= CORRECT') { |o| OPTIONS[:file] = o }
  opt.on('-d', '--default', 'Run me in default mode, this will allow me to scrape Google using my built in search queries.') { |o| OPTIONS[:default] = o }
  opt.on('-e', '--example', 'Shows my example page, gives you some pointers on how this works.') { |o| OPTIONS[:example] = o }
end.parse!

def page(site)
  Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get(site))
end

def parse(site, tag, i)
  parsing = page(site)
  parsing.css(tag)[i].to_s
end

def format_file
  Format.info('Writing to temporary file..')
  if File.exists?(OPTIONS[:file])
    file = Tempfile.new('file')
    IO.read(OPTIONS[:file]).each_line do |s|
      File.open(file, 'a+') { |format| format.puts(s) unless s.chomp.empty? }
    end
    IO.read(file).each_line do |file|
      File.open("#{PATH}/tmp/#sites.txt", 'a+') { |line| line.puts(file) }
    end
    file.unlink
    Format.info("File: #{OPTIONS[:file]}, has been formatted and saved as #sites.txt in the tmp directory.")
  else
    puts <<-_END_

             Hey now my friend, I know you're eager, I am also, but that file #{OPTIONS[:file]}
             either doesn't exist, or it's not in the directory you say it's in..

             I'm gonna need you to go find that file, move it to the correct directory and then
             run me again.

             Don't worry I'll wait!
    _END_
    .yellow.bold
  end
end

def get_urls
  Format.info("I'll run in default mode!")
  Format.info("I'm searching for possible SQL vulnerable sites, using search query #{SEARCH}")
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.user_agent = @user_agent
  page = agent.get('http://www.google.com/')
  google_form = page.form('f')
  google_form.q = "#{SEARCH}"
  url = agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
  url.links.each do |link|
    if link.href.to_s =~ /url.q/
      str = link.href.to_s
      str_list = str.split(%r{=|&})
      urls = str_list[1]
      next if urls.split('/')[2].start_with? 'stackoverflow.com', 'github.com', 'www.sa-k.net', 'yoursearch.me', 'search1.speedbit.com', 'duckfm.net', 'search.clearch.org', 'webcache.googleusercontent.com'
      next if urls == '/settings/ads/preferences?hl=en' #<= ADD HERE REMEMBER A COMMA =>
      urls_to_log = URI.decode(urls)
      Format.success("Site found: #{urls_to_log}")
      sleep(1)
      sql_syntax = ["'", "`", "--", ";"].each do |sql|
        File.open("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt", 'a+') { |s| s.puts("#{urls_to_log}#{sql}") }
      end
    end
  end
  Format.info("I've dumped possible vulnerable sites into #{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt")
end

def vulnerability_check
  case
  when OPTIONS[:default]
    file_to_read = "tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt"
  when OPTIONS[:file]
    Format.info("Let's check out this file real quick like..")
    file_to_read = "tmp/#sites.txt"
  end
  Format.info('Forcing encoding to UTF-8') unless OPTIONS[:file]
  IO.read("#{PATH}/#{file_to_read}").each_line do |vuln|
    begin
      Format.info("Parsing page for SQL syntax error: #{vuln.chomp}")
      Timeout::timeout(10) do
        vulns = vuln.encode(Encoding.find('UTF-8'), {invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ''})
        begin
          if parse("#{vulns.chomp}'", 'html', 0)[/You have an error in your SQL syntax/]
            Format.site_found(vulns.chomp)
            File.open("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_VULN.txt", "a+") { |s| s.puts(vulns) }
            sleep(1)
          else
            Format.warning("URL: #{vulns.chomp} is not vulnerable, dumped to non_exploitable.txt")
            File.open("#{PATH}/log/non_exploitable.txt", "a+") { |s| s.puts(vulns) }
            sleep(1)
          end
        rescue Timeout::Error, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
          Format.warning("URL: #{vulns.chomp} failed to load dumped to non_exploitable.txt")
          File.open("#{PATH}/log/non_exploitable.txt", "a+") { |s| s.puts(vulns) }
          next
          sleep(1)
        end
      end
    rescue RestClient::ResourceNotFound, RestClient::InternalServerError, RestClient::RequestTimeout, RestClient::Gone, RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified, RestClient::Forbidden, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Errno::ECONNREFUSED, URI::InvalidURIError, Errno::ECONNRESET, Timeout::Error, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, Zlib::GzipFile::Error, RestClient::MultipleChoices, RestClient::Unauthorized, SocketError, RestClient::BadRequest, RestClient::ServerBrokeConnection, RestClient::MaxRedirectsReached => e
      Format.err("URL: #{vuln.chomp} failed due to an error while connecting, URL dumped to non_exploitable.txt")
      File.open("#{PATH}/log/non_exploitable.txt", "a+") { |s| s.puts(vuln) }
      next
    end
  end
end

case
  when OPTIONS[:default]
    begin
      Whitewidow.spider
      sleep(1)
      Credits.credits
      sleep(1)
      Legal.legal
      get_urls
      vulnerability_check unless File.size("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt") == 0
      Format.warn("No sites found for search query: #{SEARCH}. Logging into error_log.LOG. Create a issue regarding this.") if File.size("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt") == 0
      File.open("#{PATH}/log/error_log.LOG", 'a+') { |s| s.puts("No sites found with search query #{SEARCH}") } if File.size("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt") == 0
      File.truncate("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt", 0)
      Format.info("I'm truncating SQL_sites_to_check file back to #{File.size("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt")}")
      Copy.file("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_VULN.txt", "#{PATH}/log/SQL_VULN.LOG")
      File.truncate("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_VULN.txt", 0)
      Format.info("I've run all my tests and queries, and logged all important information into #{PATH}/log/SQL_VULN.LOG")
    rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, RestClient::ServiceUnavailable, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, RestClient::BadGateway => e
      d = DateTime.now
      Format.fatal("Well this is pretty crappy.. I seem to have encountered a #{e} error. I'm gonna take the safe road and quit scanning before I break something. You can either try again, or manually delete the URL that caused the error.")
      File.open("#{PATH}/log/error_log.LOG", 'a+'){ |error| error.puts("[#{d.month}-#{d.day}-#{d.year} :: #{Time.now.strftime("%T")}]#{e}") }
      Format.info("I'll log the error inside of #{PATH}/log/error_log.LOG for further analysis.")
    end
  when OPTIONS[:file]
    begin
      Whitewidow.spider
      sleep(1)
      Credits.credits
      sleep(1)
      Legal.legal
      Format.info('Formatting file')
      format_file
      vulnerability_check
      File.truncate("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt", 0)
      Format.info("I'm truncating SQL_sites_to_check file back to #{File.size("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt")}")
      Copy.file("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_VULN.txt", "#{PATH}/log/SQL_VULN.LOG")
      File.truncate("#{PATH}/tmp/SQL_VULN.txt", 0)
      Format.info("I've run all my tests and queries, and logged all important information into #{PATH}/log/SQL_VULN.LOG") unless File.size("#{PATH}/log/SQL_VULN.LOG") == 0
    rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, RestClient::ServiceUnavailable, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, RestClient::BadGateway => e
      d = DateTime.now
      Format.fatal("Well this is pretty crappy.. I seem to have encountered a #{e} error. I'm gonna take the safe road and quit scanning before I break something. You can either try again, or manually delete the URL that caused the error.")
      File.open("#{PATH}/log/error_log.LOG", 'a+'){ |error| error.puts("[#{d.month}-#{d.day}-#{d.year} :: #{Time.now.strftime("%T")}]#{e}") }
      Format.info("I'll log the error inside of #{PATH}/log/error_log.LOG for further analysis.")
    end
  when OPTIONS[:example]
    examples_page
  else
    Format.warning('You failed to pass me a flag!')
    usage_page
end
```

IS there anything within this code, that would cause this to randomly popup? It only happens with random search queries.

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/ekultek/whitewidow)

---

**UPDATE**:

Ive discovered that Googles advertisement services link has the same extension in its URL as the one giving me problems.. However this doesn't explain why I'm getting this link, and why I can't seem to skip over it.

Comment: Nothing from anybody...?

Comment: How can one reproduce your error and help you to fix it **legally**? Is the 'default' mode legal...?

Comment: There's nothing illegal about it? It just finds, not exploits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urls = "settings/ads/preferences?hl=ru"

if urls =~ /settings\/ads\/preferences\?hl=[a-z]{2}/
    p "I'm skipped"
end

=> "I'm skipped"
```

Comment: Is a regex the only way to do it?